# Convert Int or Integer to [Word8] or [Bit]

Tags: haskell

Is there an efficient way to convert an `Int` (and preferably `Integer`) to a list of `Word8` or even a list of bits? {G,H}oogling for `Int -> [Word8]` did not yield any promising results…

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that if you want an *efficient* way of getting at the bit representation of these types, you may be barking up the wrong tree somewhere else. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 7):

Both `Int` and `Integer` are instances of the [`Bits`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#t:Bits) typeclass, so you can extract single bits at will using that class's functions.

Since `Int` is also an instance of [`Storable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html#t:Storable), you can get its size using `sizeOf`. An (inefficient) implementation of what you want for `Int`, and other types that are instances of both `Bits` and `Storable`, is thus:

```
import Foreign.Storable
import Data.Bits

bitList :: (Storable a, Bits a) => a -> [Bool]
bitList x = map (testBit x) [0..8*(sizeOf x)-1]
```

This gives for example

```
bitList (0 :: Int) == [False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False]
bitList (-1 :: Int) == [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
bitList (16 :: Word8) == [False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]
bitList (maxBound ::Word32) == [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True]
```

Comment: there is no need to use `Storable`, it is better to use [`Data.Bits.bitSizeMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Bits.html#v:bitSizeMaybe)

Comment: @maxtaldykin: Ah, I didn't know. Thanks. I'd still prefer `Storable` - it's been around for much longer than `bitSizeMaybe`. I also feel it's more appropriate for `bitList` to work with typeclasses than to return `Maybe [Bool]`.

Comment: using `Storable` prevents from getting bits of `Integer` because there is no `instance Storable Integer`

Comment: Sure, but the documentation for `bitSizeMaybe` says "returns Nothing for types that do not have a fixed bitsize, like Integer", so it won't help :-)

Comment: please see my answer, it is easy to handle `Nothing` and extract valid number of bits (which is infinite for `Integer`).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. My bad. I like your answer, then!

Answer (score 2):

Here are appropriate functions for doing that to an `Integer` ripped from the [innards of the cereal package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal-0.4.1.1/docs/src/Data-Serialize.html#unroll):

```
--
-- Fold and unfold an Integer to and from a list of its bytes
--
unroll :: Integer -> [Word8]
unroll = unfoldr step
  where
    step 0 = Nothing
    step i = Just (fromIntegral i, i `shiftR` 8)

roll :: [Word8] -> Integer
roll   = foldr unstep 0
  where
    unstep b a = a `shiftL` 8 .|. fromIntegral b
```

Comment: The code in `cereal` only calls that on `Integer`s that it first calls `abs` on; no promises for what that code does with negative values.

Answer (score 2):

Another version of approach suggested by @gspr but without requiring `Storable` (and it supports `Integer`s as a bonus!):

```
import Data.Bits

bitList :: Bits a => a -> [Bool]
bitList x =
    [ testBit x i
    | i <- maybe [0..] (enumFromTo 0 . subtract 1) (bitSizeMaybe x)
    ]
```

It correctly guesses sizes of ints and words, but beware it will give you infinite number of bits for `Integer`.

Comment: When I pass a `Int` into it, and then run `length` on the result, I get 65. Shouldn't it be 64?

Comment: That's a bug, thanks for noticing. Fixed by adding `subtract 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I extended @max-taldykin by converting it to show the bits right to left, similar to how the bits are usually shown.

```
import Data.Bits (FiniteBits, finiteBitSize, testBit)
import Data.Int (Int32)

bitList :: FiniteBits a => a -> [Bool]
bitList x = let size = finiteBitSize x
            in [testBit x i | i <- enumFromThenTo size (size - 1) 0]

bitListToNum :: Num b => [Bool] -> [b]
bitListToNum = map (\b -> case b of { True -> 1; False -> 0 })

main = do 
    let listOfBits = bitList (65 :: Int32)
    print $ bitListToNum listOfBits
```

Also provided a function to convert it to digits.

Updated here: https://gist.github.com/a7f3ba5976accc113736f3b22929dddc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data.Vector.Storable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Storable.html) and `unsafeCast` to then convert it to another int type and then pull them out by index.

```
let w32 = 800 :: Int32
    vec = singleton w32
    vec' = unsafeCase vec :: Vector Word8
in toList vec'
```

or something similar with [Ptr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html) and stuff.

**NOTE:** as it suggests this is an unsafe action so verify the data as much as you can before hand.